# css button aren't the same size

Tags: html, css

I've looked at many tutorials on this website for this problem but nothing worked. Also the code is mainly from a template that I'm modifying. How can I fix it so the button "melody" and "anne" could be the same size and not overlap each other? Here's my code:

```css
/* Links */

a,
a:focus,
a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.custom {
  width: 78px !important;
}


/* Melody */

.btn-Melody {
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: none;
  background-color: #a9cafc;
  border: 0.05rem solid #a9cafc;
}

.btn-Melody:hover {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #72a8f9;
  border: 0.05rem solid #72a8f9;
}

.btn-Melody:focus {
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: none;
  border: 0.05rem solid #72a8f9;
}


/* Anne */

.btn-Anne {
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: none;
  /* Prevent inheritance from `body` */
  background-color: #a9fcab;
  border: 0.05rem solid #a9fcab;
}

.btn-Anne:hover {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #5bff5f;
  border: 0.05rem solid #5bff5f;
}

.btn-Anne:focus {
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: none;
  /* Prevent inheritance from `body` */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0.05rem solid #fff;
}


/*
     * Base structure
     */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  /*background-image: url("Anne.png")*/
}

body {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 0.05rem 0.1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}


/* Extra markup and styles for table-esque vertical and horizontal centering */

.site-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  /* For at least Firefox */
  min-height: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.site-wrapper-inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.cover-container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}


/* Padding for spacing */

.inner {
  padding: 2rem;
}


/*
     * Header
     */

.masthead {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.masthead-brand {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link {
  padding: 0.25rem 0;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 0.25rem solid transparent;
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link:hover,
.nav-masthead .nav-link:focus {
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link+.nav-link {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.nav-masthead .active {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .masthead-brand {
    float: left;
  }
  .nav-masthead {
    float: right;
  }
}


/*
     * Cover
     */

.cover {
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

.cover .btn-lg {
  padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}


/*
     * Footer
     */

.mastfoot {
  color: #000000;
}


/*
     * Affix and center
     */

@media (min-width: 40em) {
  /* Pull out the header and footer */
  .masthead {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
  .mastfoot {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  /* Start the vertical centering */
  .site-wrapper-inner {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  /* Handle the widths */
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 100%;
    /* Must be percentage or pixels for horizontal alignment */
  }
}

@media (min-width: 62em) {
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 42rem;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="template.css">

<div class="site-wrapper">

  <div class="site-wrapper-inner">

    <div class="cover-container">

      <header class="masthead clearfix">
        <div class="inner">
          <h3 class="masthead-brand">Cover</h3>
          <nav class="nav nav-masthead">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>

      <body>

      </body>
      <main role="main" class="inner cover">

        <h1 class="cover-heading">Cover your page.</h1>
        <p class="lead">Cover is a one-page template for building simple and beautiful home pages. Download, edit the text, and add your own fullscreen background photo to make it your own.</p>
        <p class="lead">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-Melody custom">Melody</a>
          <p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-Anne custom">Anne</a>
          </p>

          <footer class="mastfoot">
            <div class="inner">
              <p>Website by
                <a href="#">ChloeM</a>.</p>
            </div>
          </footer>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

I tried to make a table, tried to add a !important for them to be a fix width but it didn't seemed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overlap of elements is happening because the second button was wrapped into a paragraph with `margin`. Take the button out of the paragraph and you're fine. You can also use padding instead of margin on your paragraphs and items won't overlap.

```css
  /* Links */

a,
a:focus,
a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.custom {
  width: 78px !important;
}


/* Melody */

.btn-Melody {
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: none;
  background-color: #a9cafc;
  border: 0.05rem solid #a9cafc;
}

.btn-Melody:hover {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #72a8f9;
  border: 0.05rem solid #72a8f9;
}

.btn-Melody:focus {
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: none;
  border: 0.05rem solid #72a8f9;
}


/* Anne */

.btn-Anne {
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: none;
  /* Prevent inheritance from `body` */
  background-color: #a9fcab;
  border: 0.05rem solid #a9fcab;
}

.btn-Anne:hover {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #5bff5f;
  border: 0.05rem solid #5bff5f;
}

.btn-Anne:focus {
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: none;
  /* Prevent inheritance from `body` */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0.05rem solid #fff;
}


/*
     * Base structure
     */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  /*background-image: url("Anne.png")*/
}

body {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 0.05rem 0.1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}


/* Extra markup and styles for table-esque vertical and horizontal centering */

.site-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  /* For at least Firefox */
  min-height: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.site-wrapper-inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.cover-container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}


/* Padding for spacing */

.inner {
  padding: 2rem;
}


/*
     * Header
     */

.masthead {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.masthead-brand {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link {
  padding: 0.25rem 0;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 0.25rem solid transparent;
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link:hover,
.nav-masthead .nav-link:focus {
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link+.nav-link {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.nav-masthead .active {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .masthead-brand {
    float: left;
  }
  .nav-masthead {
    float: right;
  }
}


/*
     * Cover
     */

.cover {
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

.cover .btn-lg {
  padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}


/*
     * Footer
     */

.mastfoot {
  color: #000000;
}


/*
     * Affix and center
     */

@media (min-width: 40em) {
  /* Pull out the header and footer */
  .masthead {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
  .mastfoot {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  /* Start the vertical centering */
  .site-wrapper-inner {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  /* Handle the widths */
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 100%;
    /* Must be percentage or pixels for horizontal alignment */
  }
}

@media (min-width: 62em) {
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 42rem;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="template.css">

<div class="site-wrapper">

  <div class="site-wrapper-inner">

    <div class="cover-container">

      <header class="masthead clearfix">
        <div class="inner">
          <h3 class="masthead-brand">Cover</h3>
          <nav class="nav nav-masthead">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>

      <body>

      </body>
      <main role="main" class="inner cover">

        <h1 class="cover-heading">Cover your page.</h1>
        <p class="lead">Cover is a one-page template for building simple and beautiful home pages. Download, edit the text, and add your own fullscreen background photo to make it your own.</p>
        <p class="lead">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-Melody custom">Melody</a>

          <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-Anne custom">Anne</a>


          <footer class="mastfoot">
            <div class="inner">
              <p>Website by
                <a href="#">ChloeM</a>.</p>
            </div>
          </footer>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```